# iso-8895-1 to xml acceptable UTF-8

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I am parsing text/html from web pages into an xml feed, the text/html is encoded iso-8895-1 while the XML feed must be UTF-8. I have used html entities, but am having to manually replace loads of characters, here is what I have so far (still not parsing all text)

```
$desc = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\r\n"),"",$desc);
    $desc = str_replace(array("’","‘","”","“"),"'",$desc);
  $desc = str_replace("£","&pound;",$desc);
    $desc = str_replace("é","&eacute;",$desc);
    $desc = str_replace("²","2",$desc);
    $desc = str_replace(array("-","•"),"&dash;",$desc);
$desc = htmlentities($desc, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: It looks like you are building your XML by gluing together strings. Don't do that. Use an XML library, you can tell it your output encoding and it will take care of any encoding needs you have. (`htmlentities` won't do that, since all but a few of them are undefined for arbitrary XML)

Comment: Actually I am building my xml using $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); and iterating through an array appending children and text nodes. This is merely to prepare the text for one of the nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php). It will allow you to use native characters in UTF-8 as well - no need for HTML entities.

```
$data = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $text);
```

when doing encoding **from UTF-8** to another character set, use IGNORE or TRANSLIT to drop or transliterate non-translatable characters.

alternatively, the `mb_*` functions shown by @Gumbo will work as well.

Comment: +1, possibly add `//TRANSLIT` to prevent characters that can't be represented in ISO-8859-1 to break the string.

Comment: Um, the character set of the ISO 8859-1 is a subset of the Unicode character set. So there is no need to ignore or transliterate anything because there is no difference: charset(ISO 8859-1) \ charset(Unicode) = ∅.

Comment: Don't forget to *also* modify any `META` tag that gives the charset, since it will probably be inaccurate afterwards.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: An XML feed probably doesn’t have a `META` element – at least not those I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) or [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding):

```
$desc = utf8_encode($desc);
// OR
$desc = mb_convert_encoding($dest, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Both will convert the encoding from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8.